# Memory leak in iOS App swift with SignalR

Tags: ios, swift, signalr

I'm using `signalr` to update the values in the Swift app.
Following is my `SignalRService` class implementation class.

```swift
    public class SignalRService {
        
        private var connection: HubConnection
        
        private let intIndesiesArgument : String = "argument1,argument2,..."
        private let commoditiesArgument : String = "argument1,argument2,..."
        
        init(url: URL,delegate : SignalRDataUpdateDelegate) {
            connection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: url)
                .withLogging(minLogLevel: .info)
                .withAutoReconnect()
                .build()
            connection.delegate = self
            
            
            connection.on(method: Events.PricesUpdated.rawValue, callback: { response in
                do {
                    
                    let channel = try response.getArgument(type: String.self)
                    if channel == Channels.commodities.rawValue{
                        if response.hasMoreArgs() {
                            let dataModel : CommoditiesModel = try response.getArgument(type: CommoditiesModel.self)
                            delegate.updateComodities(dataModel: dataModel)
                        }
                        
                    }else{
                        if response.hasMoreArgs() {
                            let dataModel : CommoditiesModel = try response.getArgument(type: CommoditiesModel.self)
                            delegate.updateIntIndecies(dataModel: dataModel)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    //print(error)
                }
            })
            
            connection.start()
            
        }
        
        func disconnectSignalR(){
            connection.stop()
        }
        
        private func handleMessage(_ message: String, from user: String) {
            // Do something with the message.
            print(message)
        }
        
    }
    
       extension SignalRService : HubConnectionDelegate{
        
        public func connectionDidOpen(hubConnection: HubConnection) {
            
            connection.invoke(method: Events.Subscribe.rawValue, arguments:[Channels.commodities.rawValue,commoditiesArgument]) { error in
                if let e = error {
                    //self.appendMessage(message: "Error: \(e)")
                    print(e)
                }else{
                    print("Succefully subscribe")
                }
                
            }
            
            connection.invoke(method: Events.Subscribe.rawValue, arguments:[Channels.intlIndices.rawValue,intIndesiesArgument]) { error in
                
                if let e = error {
                    //self.appendMessage(message: "Error: \(e)")
                    print(e)
                }else{
                    print("Succefully subscribe")
                }
    
            }
            print(hubConnection.connectionId ?? "")
        }
        
        public func connectionDidFailToOpen(error: Error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        public func connectionDidClose(error: Error?) {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
        
        
    }
```

Using this in `ViewController` as follow. Establish a connection when the view controller becomes active and disconnect when it disappears.

```swift
    Class MyViewController : BaseViewController , SignalRDataUpdateDelegate {

      private var connection: SignalRService?
    
        @objc func didBecomeActive() {
            connection = SignalRService(url: URL(string: "https://myURL.com/update")!, 
              delegate: self)
        }
    
        override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
            connection?.disconnectSignalR()
        }
    
    }
```

It works fine and updates values but there is one problem the Memory graph goes up every single second when it receives the new value. Until App got crashed after it exceeded the memory limit. And through the following exception.

> ```
> RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=2098 MB, unused=0x0)
> ```

I don't know what went wrong here.